# Question about absolute value of the addition of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, absolute-value

I would say the answer is "The angle between A and B is 120" because it |A| describes the L2 norm and every other option could not yield a correct result
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4yQ9.png)

Am I right? If so, explain why. The friend that asked this said it's wrong and it was because of a Chegg study post so I want to know why he was right/wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|A + B|^2 = |A|^2 + |B|^2 +2(A\cdot B)$ which yields
$$
\begin{align}
A\cdot B
&= \frac{1}{2}\{|A + B|^2 - (|A|^2 + |B|^2)\}\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}|A|^2
\end{align}
$$
Since $A\cdot B = |A|^2\cos\theta$, we have

1. $|A| = |B| = 0$
   or
2. $|A| = |B| \not= 0$ and $\cos\theta = -1/2$, which gives one of the solutions $\theta = 120\deg$.

The problem missed case 1 though.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking of case 1 but realized it was not an answer.